# "Founded on [date]" vs. "Founded in [date]"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I want to put a variation of the following just above a company description, but I'm wondering which preposition I should use:

> Business Founded On December 2011
>   Business Founded In December 2011

Comment: ...I am not sure which sentence is which...

Comment: It's **in December 2011**, or **on December 25th 2011**. Choice of preposition depends on whether it's on a specific *day*, or in some extended timeframe such as a month, season, or year. The standard wording is **Established 2011** (it's unusual to specify the month or date thereof).

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage! I just wanted to let you know I've made a few edits to your question for clarity and [formatting](http://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help); in the future, if you could try to be a little more precise with your titles, that would be great! And please let me know if you have any questions about the site.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing my proud tradition of taking credit for something that FumbleFingers already answered in the comments...

Short Version: **In** would be appropriate here, **On** would be appropriate if you were specifying an exact day.

Long version: Using these definitions...

**In** - used to indicate inclusion within space, a place, or limits

**On** - so as to be attached to or unified with

...we can think of specifying month only as telling us the founding date is including within the limits of the month, while specifying a day tells us that the founding date is attached to that specific day.